# Dealing with no input and setting a value for it in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, textbox, integer

I have textboxes which a user is supposed to insert a numerical value. If the user misses a box the missed boxes value should be set as 0. How can I do this with a if statement? This is what I have tried but I can't seem to get it to work. When I miss a textbox is simply doesn't show "0" it's left blank.

```
$missed = 0;

if($usernumber == "")    { 
$usernumber = $missed;
}
```

Comment: How is $usernumber getting set? To grab input you need to use the $_GET or $_POST vars

Comment: Post more few lines of code.

Comment: *When I miss a textbox is simply doesn't show "0" it's left blank* ... `(string) 0 == ""` so that's what you'd expect.

Comment: I Think. OP Went For *Dinner/Lunch/Breakfast* Or *May Be He Left Office* Or *Not Interested In Below Answers*. Not Replying, Though.

Comment: I tried the answers below however when I ran it, it still gave me a no number. The answer was simply left blank and had no answer, which should be 0.

Comment: I got it working thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php    
$missed = 0;
if (!isset($_POST['usernumber'])) {
    $username = $missed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using post method then you can check like this

```
$missed = 0;
$usernumber =$_POST['usernumber'];
if($usernumber=='')
{
  $usernumber = $missed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention multiple text boxes so to avoid repeating the same code for each one I'd probably recommend doing it as a loop. I started doing this as am "empty" check on the _POST var but then realised that, if you need the answers to be a number then !is_numeric() is a better way to ensure they provide a number too.

```
// Textbox field names
$myPostedTextBoxes = Array("usernumber","anotherbox1","anotherbox2");

// Convert empty values to "0"
foreach($myPostTextBoxes as $tb){
    $_POST[$tb] = !is_numeric($_POST["tb"])?"0":$_POST[$tb];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$_POST['usernumber']) $usernumber = $missed;
```